# Can't go back using the back button after navigating from a specific fragment to another

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

In my app have a navigation flow like this

```
AuthFragment --> SellerMainScreenFragment -----> pay_nav_graph (Nested Graph)
                                    |
                                    |----> CreditFragment---------
                                    |                            |
                                    |----> CreditAddFragment <---|
                                                            |
                                                            |-------> TransactionResultFragment
```

Now when the app try to navigate from `SellerMainScreenFragment`  to  `CreditAddFragment`, everything works fine and upon pressing the back button in the latter fragment, the app returns to the former. The navigation code is

```kotlin
adapter.wasAddBalPressed.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
  if (it != NO_VAL)
     findNavController().navigate(SellerMainScreenFragmentDirections.actionSellerListScreenFragmentToCreditAddFragment(it))
})
```

But when the app navigates from `CreditFragment` to `CreditAddFragment`, upon pressing the back button in the `CreditAddFragment`, the app doesn't return to the previous fragment. The code goes :

```kotlin
val action = CreditFragmentDirections.actionCreditFragmentToCreditAddFragment(viewModel.userSellerPhoneNo)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

I have tried setting a custom `onBackPressedCallback` on the `OnBackPressedDispatcher` like so

```kotlin
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    findNavController().popBackStack()
    remove()
}
```

But even then it doesn't return to the previous fragment if it is the `CreditFragment` but in the case of the `SellerMainScreenFragment`, it works as intended.

I have also correctly set the `app:defaultNavHost = true` in the `NavHostFragment`.

At this point I have tried cleaning the project, invalidating the caches, cold booting the emulator and I tried to debug, but even then I can't find anything suspicious.

So if anyone can help out, please try to do so.Thanks.

**Edit-1** :-

This is the navigation xml file that I am currently using in the app

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
    app:startDestination="@id/authFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.AuthFragment"
        android:label="AuthFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_auth">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_authFragment_to_sellerListScreenFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sellerListScreenFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/authFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sellerListScreenFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.SellerMainScreenFragment"
        android:label="SellerListScreenFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_screen">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/listFragment_to_creditFragment"
            app:destination="@id/creditFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sellerListScreenFragment_to_pay_nav_graph"
            app:destination="@id/pay_nav_graph" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sellerListScreenFragment_to_creditAddFragment"
            app:destination="@id/creditAddFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/creditFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.CreditFragment"
        android:label="CreditFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_credit_enter_no">
        <!--<action
            android:id="@+id/action_creditFragment_self"
            app:destination="@id/creditFragment" />-->
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_creditFragment_to_creditAddFragment"
            app:destination="@id/creditAddFragment" />
    </fragment>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/creditAddFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.CreditAddFragment"
        android:label="CreditAddFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_credit_add">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_creditAddFragment_self"
            app:destination="@id/creditAddFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_creditAddFragment_to_transactionResultFragment"
            app:destination="@id/transactionResultFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="sellerPhoneNo"
            app:argType="string" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/transactionResultFragment"
        android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.TransactionResultFragment"
        android:label="TransactionResultFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_transaction_result">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_transactionResultFragment_self"
            app:destination="@id/transactionResultFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="sellerPhoneNo"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_sellerListScreenFragment"
        app:destination="@id/sellerListScreenFragment" />

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/pay_nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/payFragment">

        <argument
            android:name="sellerPhoneNo"
            app:argType="string" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/payFragment"
            android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.PayFragment"
            android:label="PayFragment">
            <argument
                android:name="sellerPhoneNo"
                app:argType="string" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_payFragment_to_processPaymentFragment"
                app:destination="@id/processPaymentFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_payFragment_self"
                app:destination="@id/payFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/processPaymentFragment"
            android:name="com.example.paylater.ui.ProcessPaymentFragment"
            android:label="ProcessPaymentFragment" />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

**Edit-2**:
Even after explicitly calling

```
findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.creditFragment, false)
```

in the `onBackPressedCallback`, it still doesn't return to the previous fragment (`CreditFragment`)

Comment: So where does the back button goes if it doesn't go to `CreditFragment` ?

Comment: Try using this line of code : `findNavController().navigateUp()` instead of using `popBackStack`. And you could pass the layout id which you want you to go to your back stack using the specific id.

Comment: @MaryJane Nothing happens, it just stays on the same fragment, no matter the no. of times I press it.

Comment: Can you show us your nav graph XML

Comment: Please try the code I mentioned above, It might fix it.

Comment: @MaryJane Thanks for the suggestion, but sorry to say that it too doesn't cause the problem to go away, and even now it returns properly if the app navigates to it from `SellerMainScreenFragment`, but not if it does from the `CreditFragment`.

Comment: @MohamedHassan I'll try to.

Comment: Ok. printing your back tack list might help here if you could add it to the description. and also if you could include the navigation graph also.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped. I managed to solve it. More details in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the app was observing a `MediatorLiveData` in the `CreditFragment` and when it's value changed the navigation to the `CreditAddFragment` happened.

But for some reason the `MediatorLiveData`'s value was maintained as it navigated to the next fragment, and upon pressing the back button, the app navigated to the previous fragment, but then *navigated again* to the `CreditAddFragment` instantly, leading to it seeming as if the back navigation didm't happen.

I found this when I put `Log` statements in both fragments' `onViewCreated()`, after @MaryJane had suggested looking at the backstack behaviour.

Then only did I see this strange behaviour. So a big thanks to @MaryJane and  for helping me solve this, and sorry to everyone for asking such a question.